# Does a referenced document in FireStore know about its parent?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am playing around with FireStore, and I am wondering if I should add an id to a referenced document which points to the "parent" document.

My example is as follows:
I have a collection of **users**, and each user has a sub-collection, **votes**. Should I store the `userId` as a field in a vote? Or is that redundant?

[image]

Comment: Do you need the user id there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think you should. Inevitably, when using nested collections, there may be times you will call for all votes using a collectionGroup query. Meaning, you may want to eventually call all collections called `votes` regardless of the user, perhaps all votes "for" something.

In this case, I think having the userId easily accessible will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure if I could see the "parent" from the child using a $ref, or something like that on the child. However, I am guessing there is no built in mechanic for a reference to know which one is referencing it. I guess that was what I wanted to know. – If the child has a reference to the parent as a built in mechanic in FireStore. If not, adding the userId is a good idea as you say.

Comment: You actually can do `.parent` on a returned document to get it. I just think if you know where you're storing the vote (since you specify the user ID anyway) you might as well store it in the document as a field so you don't have to bother with `.parent`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the ID there if you are making a query that requires it to be present.  Otherwise, it's completely up to you if you would like to store it there redundantly or not.

Comment: Thank you for providing helpful videos about Firebase security rules for us! And thank you for the answer.